# accumulateWeighted causes the images to darken

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv's accumulateWeighted function to get a running average of a camera stream. However I have observed that for lower alpha values < 0.1) the output of the accumulateWeighted functions becomes very dark. Is this is expected behaviour of this function and if not that what am I doing wrong? I am passing it a CV_8UC3 image and receive an CV_32FC3 output which I then display by converting it back to CV_8UC3.

Comment: I think you should initialize dst (the second parameter) with the (first) input image, converted to float, see here  http://opencvpython.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet that reproduce your result?

Comment: @RosaGronchi thanks a lot that helped..maybe if you can put that as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `dst` - the second parameter with the first input image (converted to float)

See example [here](http://opencvpython.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/background-extraction-using-running.html)